# Savon and Ruby to call a webservice

Tags: ruby, savon

I have a SOAP request

```
<Register>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" >
<soap:Header/><soap:Body>
<Register>
<identifiers>?</identifiers>
<userId></userId>
<password pwct="?">?</password>
<locale>?</locale>
</Register>

Fully Formed Request that works is 

        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <soap:Header/>
        <soap:Body>
         <Register>
          <identifiers>
            <DIdentifiers>
         <Section name="IDENTIFIERS">
    <Property name="Type" value="Support" />        
    <Property name="Version" value="3.80 Jan 03 2013" />
    <Property name="Timestamp" value="2015/06/08 11:57:48 GMT" />
    <Property name="SerialNumber" value="00004" />
    <Property name="Hostname" value="gmail.com" />
    <Property name="ProductNumber" value="C00004" />
    </Section><Section name="INTERFACE_IDENTIFIERS">
    <Property name="InterfaceAddress" value="45.34.54.6"/>
    <Property name="InterfaceMacAddress" value="00579FGHslkf"/>
    </Section>
    </DIdentifiers>
    </identifiers>
       <userId> <userId>
       <password pwct="TRUE">shirl123</reg:password>
        <locale>en_US</locale>
     <Register>
    </soap:Body>
   </soap:Envelope>

I have added 

    WSDL client = Savon::client(wsdl: " ")

And calling method  

    client.call(:Register, message: { })
```

How can I send the above parameters in Ruby? Could not figure out the correct way to pass parameters

```
I'm passing 
DeviceIdentifiers: {
    :Section=> {
     { :Property    => nil,
       :attributes! => { :Property => { "name" => Type, "value" =>Support} }
    }
}
```

But this doesnot work..

I referred to this
http://savonrb.com/version1/executing-soap-requests.html

Comment: hi and welcome to stack overflow. What ruby code did you try? (even if it's not working, we can help you debug it). Can you please edit your question and put the ruby code there? (don't put code in the comments cos the formatting is awful). Also - add anything else that may be relevant to your question eg what are you trying to do? what errors did you get when you tried your ruby? etc

Comment: Don't ask [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897293/new-to-savon-and-ruby) again, improve your earlier question.

Comment: **(don't put code in the comments cos the formatting is awful).**

Comment: use version 2. there is no reason to get stuck with the old version. your payload goes into the `message` hash of your call in Savon.